# how to shrink an image (matplotlib)

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

Given the image in the following format in the shape[200,200]:

```
im = plt.imread("images_learning/Triangle_6be2b212-2a8b-11ea-8123-8363a7ec19e6.png").mean(axis = 2)
```

How can one shrink it to the shape of [10,10]?
It's important to keep it as a matplotlib object.

Comment: Even the matplotlib documentation uses PIL for resizing.

Comment: PIL works but you can also just use `scipy.ndimage.zoom` if you want to keep the image a numpy array. [Link to docs.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html)